# Xamarin Forms Update Page Content

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin forms app and I am trying to update the content on one of the pages from the output of an API call without refreshing the page.

Where would I put a loop to make the API call and update the view model every X seconds? I can run all the API calls I want in the constructor but I can't seem to find a way to have this happen once the page is loaded.

Comment: use a Timer, not a loop

Comment: Use a Timer.  In timer's Elapsed method, make the call. Then do anything that affects UI inside `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => { ... });`

Comment: Do you have an example of this you can link to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to update the content on one of the pages,you could put the code inside the timer to interact on the UI thread, it should be done within a `BeginInvokeOnMainThread` expression, which will be nested inside the timer (see below).
You could refer to below sample code:

```
Device.StartTimer (new TimeSpan (0, 0, 60), () =>
{
    // do something every 60 seconds
    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread (() => 
    {
      // interact with UI elements
    });
    return true; // runs again, or false to stop
});
```

MS official reference [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/Xamarin.Forms.Device.StartTimer?view=xamarin-forms#Xamarin_Forms_Device_StartTimer_System_TimeSpan_System_Func_System_Boolean__).